# how can I create OpenGL context using Windows memory dc (c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

In my Windows MFC application, in its View class I created an OpenGL context using View's DC:

```
HANDLE * hdc = GetDC()->m_hdc;
int nPixelFormat;
static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), // Size of this structure
1, // Version of this structure
PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | // Draw to window (not bitmap)
PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | // Support OpenGL calls
PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER, // Double -buffered mode
PFD_TYPE_RGBA, // RGBA Color mode
24, // Want 24bit color
0,0,0,0,0,0, // Not used to select mode
0,0, // Not used to select mode
0,0,0,0,0, // Not used to select mode
32, // Size of depth buffer
0, // Not used to select mode
0, // Not used to select mode
PFD_MAIN_PLANE, // Draw in main plane
0, // Not used to select mode
0,0,0 }; // Not used to select mode

// Choose a pixel format that best matches that described in pfd
nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdC, &pfd);
// Set the pixel format for the device context
assert(SetPixelFormat(hdC, nPixelFormat, &pfd));

HGLRC m_hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
assert(m_hrc);
wglMakeCurrent(m_hdc,m_hrc);
```

All the code above works all right, and I can do OpenGL drawings as expected.

But , What  I need now is to change the DC to memory dc instead of window DC . To be exact, how can I use the 'hmemDC' bellow to create an OpenGL context like the way I did above with window DC:

```
CRect rct;
GetClientRect(&rct);
HDC hmemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(pDC->m_hDC);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC->m_hDC,rct.Width(),rct.Height());
```

with the same pixel format constructed above, I came across the "Invalid pixel format" error in calling wglCreateContext() , can not success in getting the correct OpenGL context.

I googled a lot , and tryed to change some of the values of pixel format, the result was the same.

Is it possible to create OpenGL context with Windows Memory DC? and if it is how should I do it?

Edit: 
This is why I need a bitmap ( or Memory DC ):  I created a 2d map rendering library which uses OpenGL.  The client want to use this library to render background map, and draw its own symbols on top of it . But, they prefer to use Windows GDI other than OpenGL to draw their symbols.  So I thought if I can provide them with a bitmap or a Mmeory DC, they could to what they want. Any better solutions?  Am I in the right direction? Or it is a total bad idea to provide such a 2d library in OpenGL backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be done in a useful way.

You *can* in principle render to a bitmap by using the `PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP` flag instead of `PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW` in the [PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, doing so will *disable* all hardware accelearated rendering. This will fall back to Microsofts default OpenGL 1.1 implementation.

If you want hw-accleration and/or modern GL, you either need a window or some offscreen buffer like a pbuffer, which is available via the [WGL_ARB_pbuffer](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_pbuffer.txt) extension. However, in modern GL, you are probably better off creating a window which is just never shown, and using a [Frambeuffer Object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) as the offscreen render target.

In either case, you will have to copy the data back to the CPU, if you need it as some bitmap there.

Comment: This is why I need a bitmap ( or Memory DC ):  I created a 2d map rendering library which uses OpenGL.  The client want to use this library to render background map, and draw its own symbols on top of it . But, they prefer to use Windows GDI other than OpenGL to draw their symbols.  So I thought if I can provide them with a bitmap or a Mmeory DC, they could to what they want. Any better solutions?  Am I in the right direction? Or it is a total bad idea to provide such a 2d library in OpenGL backend.

Comment: Another question: I used a hidden window and FBO to do the offscreen rendering. After that , how can i copy the pixel data from FBO to another window dc. I tried glReadPixel and SetBitmapBits api , which  does not seem right.

Comment: well, `glReadPixels` is the correct way to read the image back from the GL. For how to efficiently getting the results into a bitmap, I don't know.

Comment: I finally figure it out. Call SetDIBitsToDevice after calling glReadPixel will do the job.

Comment: @derhass, hi (I got here searching on google)! what is the reason for preferring window instead of an offscreen pbuffer?

Comment: @Mano-Wii: pbuffers are an extension, while FBOs are a core feature of OpenGL since 3.0.

Comment: yes, but I plan to use a dummy pbuffer just to get an dc that is compatible with core opengl. I wonder if I should also avoid a pbuffer in this case. And use a window.

Comment: Well, on windows, you will need a dummy window required for the dummy GL context to get the WGL extension for the pbuffer in the first place, so if you try to avoid creating a window at all, you will fail. If on the other hand creating a dummy window is fine, why would it be an issue to keep such a window around during the rest of the application? You never have to map it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Put in few words: You can't create arbitrary OpenGL contexts for MemDCs. At least no kind of OpenGL context you'd actually want to use.

If your goal is off-screen rendering either create a PBuffer-DC; which requires to create a OpenGL context first which in turn required to create a window and setting its pixel format. Or you can just create a window and a OpenGL context for it and use a framebuffer object.